# Using regexp in Matlab to find specific file from beginning and end components of filename

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a set of CSV files with name structure SC[x]wordswordswords[ending].csv where [x] is an increasing integer, and [ending] is 2 characters before the filetype. eg: SC3performanceOverview*ES*.csv; SC4performanceSubstitute*SL*.csv, etc. My current code is as follows

```
searchNum = 3;
searchCrit = strcat('Sc', num2str(searchNum));
searchEnding = 'TS';

list = dir('*.csv');
list = {list.name};
rgx1 = regexp(list,searchCrit);
rgx1 =~ cellfun('isempty',rgx1);
listNew = list(rgx1);
rgx2 = regexp(listNew,searchEnding);
rgx2 =~ cellfun('isempty',rgx2);
OutputName = char(listNew(rgx2))
```

This is based on a code snippet I had floating around in old code. This seems like an incredibly clunky way of using regexp, and I'm sure there must be a better way of finding my file with just one use of regexp, but I am unsure as to how. MathWorks hasn't been much help, and I couldn't find this exact question elsewhere on SO. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `strcat('^', searchCrit, '.*', searchEnding,'[.]csv$')` instead of the first regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, if you make this an answer, I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use one regex to filter the results:

```
strcat('^', searchCrit, '.*', searchEnding,'[.]csv$')
```

The pattern means:

- `^` - start of string
- `searchCrit` - your `searchCrit` subpattern
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `searchEnding` - the `searchEnding` subpattern
- `[.]csv$` - a literal dot, `csv` and the end of string anchor (`$`).